# ¿Como imprimir de forma lineal una matriz de 2x3, en una sola línea?

Tags: python, numpy

Deseo poder imprimir un arreglo como el siguiente:

```
[[0. 0. 0.] [0. 0. 0.]]
```

Tengo conocimiento de que el arreglo solo puede ser llenado con enteros, strings y floats. También con object, pero no queda igual.

Entonces, deseo crear una matriz a través de un código como el siguiente :

```
matriz = np.zeros((2,3),dtype = algo)
```

Ese algo, hará que la matriz:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se muestre del siguiente modo:

```
[[0. 0. 0.] [0. 0. 0.]]
```

Entonces, mi incógnita es **ese** algo.

Comment: No hay arreglos en Python, sino listas. Para construir una lista colocas los valores/cadenas/objetos separados por comas y lo encierras todo entre `[]`

Comment: `print(arreglo)`

Comment: Si existen los arreglos en python, a través de ma librería numpy

Comment: esos no son arreglos, son `numpy array`

Comment: Bueno, estoy trabajando con numpy en python y, para hacer más clara la pregunta, la acabo de editar.

Comment: @Kevin Gilces El título no va con la pregunta, generar un arreglo ya lo has hecho con `np.zero()`.

Answer (score 0):

Si hablamos de mostrar en pantalla con ese formato y no guardar una variable con ese formato (que no se podría sin separar los elementos con una coma `,`).

en tipo `string` puedes remplazar las '`,`' por un espacio vacío ' ' e imprimirlo, así:

```py
lista=[[0.,0.,0.],[0.,0.,0.]]
listaString=str(lista)
print(listaString.replace(","," "))
```

Salida:

```
[[0.0  0.0  0.0]  [0.0  0.0  0.0]]
```

Numpy arrays, parece agregar una nueva línea `\n` por lo que el código sin usar regex sería:

```py
import numpy as np

lista=np.array([[0.,0.,0.],[0.,0.,0.]])
listaString=str(lista)
print(listaString.replace("\n"," ").replace(","," "))
```

Salida:

```
[[0.0  0.0  0.0]  [0.0  0.0  0.0]]
```